# Eclipse android developer an internal error occurred

Tags: java, android, eclipse

An internal error occurred during: "Launching app".
java.lang.StackOverflowError. Got red exclamation marks on both my main android project and my test project. in my logcat it says:

```
Error invoking for backup on @pm@ stackoverflow
```

Anyone have any idea what parts of the project I should check?

Comment: Check any recursion code.

Comment: Definitely check any recursive code, also the error should tell you the line that the problem is happening on, if you could post us the code at that point we might be able to help